# How to make an optional upload file in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to make an optional input upload file in symfony.
In my formbuilder:

```
->add('img1', 'file', array(
    'label' => 'Logo',
    'attr' => array(
        'required' => false
    )
))
```

And in the Entity:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="img1", type="text", nullable="true")
```

But when I submit the form, I steel have to complete the file input...
How can I make it optional ?

Thanks for help

Comment: First, correct the boolean value: nullable=true, without the quotes. If you are using Sf2.5, it should required: false automatically.

Comment: Ok I remove the quotes

Comment: When does the error occur? What is the message?

Comment: I fact it is just the required="required" HTML5 attribut...

Comment: did you clear your cache?